# Adding a block with query in homepage

Tags: categories, wp-query

i want my 2 post blocks to show by Categories not recent And not by category.

[image]

```
<!-- Latest posts -->
<div class="home-section">
  <div class="container"> <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2> <?php echo _e( 'گالری', '' );?></h2>
        <span> <?php echo _e( 'نمونه کارهای انجام شده', '' );?></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-cover">
      <?php 
      $count=3;
      $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $count,  // Limit count 
        );
      $recent = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => "3" ) );

      $query = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="grid-box">
          <div class="grid-pic">
            <?php 
              $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
              $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
              $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 720, 480, true,true,true ); //resize & crop the image
              ?>
            <?php if($image) : ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /> </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-entry">
            <div class="grid_title">
              <h2> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h2>
              <div class="grid-meta">
                <span> <?php echo _e( 'این پست در:', 'fabthemes' );?> <?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>
                <?php
                  $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                  echo string_limit_words($excerpt,25);
                ?>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>

  </div> </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest Posts end -->


<!-- Latest posts -->
<div class="home-section">
  <div class="container"> <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2> <?php echo _e( 'مقالات', '' );?> </h2>
        <span> <?php echo _e( 'نمونه کارهای انجام شده', '' );?></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-cover">
      <?php 
      $count=3; 
      $args = array(

            'posts_per_page' => $count,  // Limit count
        );
      $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1' );
      $query = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="grid-box">
          <div class="grid-pic">
            <?php 
              $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
              $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
              $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 720, 480, true,true,true ); //resize & crop the image
              ?>
            <?php if($image) : ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /> </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-entry">
            <div class="grid_title">
              <h2> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h2>
              <div class="grid-meta">
                <span> <?php echo _e( 'این پست در:', 'fabthemes' );?> <?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>
                <?php
                  $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                  echo string_limit_words($excerpt,25);
                ?>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>

  </div> </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest Posts end -->
```

Comment: Simply change your query arguments accordingly

Comment: yes it should be somthing like this: $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=4' ); 
i got problem with syntax , it doesnt have any effect :\

Comment: You should state that in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your queries you are doing it wrong. You are running a separate instance of `WP_Query` for every argument set

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => $count, // Limit count ); 
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1' ); 
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Should be

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => $count, 'cat' => 1 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```